# Resizable Text Box/Area

Tags: asp.net, controls, textarea

I need to have a textbox or textarea that I can resize to expand the viewable area, if desired.  Currenltly my html is layed out in a table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <Grid>
    </td>
    <td>
      <TextArea>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

There should be a line between this grid and the textarea, so if I expand one, the other one shrinks and vice-versa.  I experimented with some jQuery, but I would think there would be a simple asp.net control that could accomplish this.  Anyone know what I could use for this seemingly simple task?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using the Telerik.RadSplitter

Answer (score 1):

How about jQuery UI Resizable?

Check out this one: http://jqueryui.com/resizable/#textarea

Here is the whole page. You might check on some options that resizable has.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Resizable - Textarea</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <style>
  .ui-resizable-se {
    bottom: 17px;
  }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#resizable" ).resizable({
      handles: "se"
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<textarea id="resizable" rows="5" cols="20"></textarea>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This isn't working for me.  Here is my control: <textarea runat="server" class="resizable" ID="Notes_TextBox" rows="22" cols="25" />, my scripts:  <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
 <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
 <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
 <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: and the jQuery: 
        $(function() {
            $('.resizable').resizable({
                handles: 'se'
            });
        });  Any idea what's going wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: I tried your code, but it only shows a page with the textarea without any resizing capabilities.  I'm able to enter text and it is scrollable.  However if i hover over the sides of the textbox, I can't drag the edges to resize the box.

Comment: I think its working fine. Please give a link of your page that you think its not working. This way I can take a look at your code.

Answer (score 1):

The AjaxControlToolkit has a ResizableControl extender - see http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ResizableControl/ResizableControl.aspx

To use this, you'd download the AjaxControlToolkit and add a reference to it in your project. You'll also need to register the controls it gives you, you can do this in individual pages if you want using the `<% Register` directive at the top of your ASPX page, but these days I find the easiest way is to register it in web.config. Add this block into your web.config under the `<system.web>` section:

```
<pages>
    <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxtoolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" /> 
    </controls>
</pages>
```

And then in your page, you'd attach the extender to your grid like this:

```
<asp:gridview id="MyGridView" ... >
</asp:gridview>
<ajaxtoolkit:ResizableControlExtender TargetControlId="MyGrid" />
<hr/>
<asp:textbox id="MyTextArea" ... />
```

From your question, I think you're only wanting to resize vertically, so you'd want to set the MinimumWidth and MaximumWidth properties to the same value. The trickiness would come in reducing the size of one as you increase the size of the other, although the extender gives you events that you can hook some JavaScript into that may well be able to do this.

Comment: So, I have to download the Ajax Control Toolkit and then I can use this control in my code?

Comment: @Music Magi I've added some markup that should guide you in using the toolkit. If I get time later I'll have a look into the JavaScript side of it too.